# How to draw first Homomorphism Theorem’s Graph

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Good evening,

I’d like to know whether there’s a way to exactly represent the following graph in latex, i tried using ‘cycles’ but the result didn’t satisfy me.

There’s a way to exactly represent it?

Thank you all, any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that can be okay, with comment of OP @egreg: see the comment below.
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
G \arrow[rr, "f"] \arrow[rd, "\pi"'] &  & H \\
 & G/k \arrow[ru, "f_k"'] & 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Just for comparison using `xy` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
G \ar[rr]^f \ar[dr]_{\pi} &  & H \\
     & G/k \ar[ru]_{f_k} &
}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be perhaps nicer with `\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]`. It's an uppercase K, anyway.